# How can I apply correctly a radio button in a grid extjs?

Tags: extjs, grid, radio-button, extjs3, gridpanel

I am working locally. I used a function to display the radio button inside the grid, and then I call the function in the `renderer`. I know it's wrong, this is just to show you what I want.

I don't know how to apply the radio button to work for each row.

I use extjs 3.4.

Sorry by my english and by disorder.

This is the Array:

```
var data_metas =    [['INGRESE META N°1','','','','','','100%','100%'],
                     ['INGRESE META N°2','','','','','','100%','100%'],
                     ['INGRESE META N°3','','','','','','100%','100%']];
```

This is the ArrayStore:

```
var store_grid_metas = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                  fields: [
                     {name: 'Meta'},
                     {name: '100%'},
                     {name: '75%'},
                     {name: '50%'},
                     {name: '25%'},
                     {name: '0%'},
                     {name: 'Ponderación'},
                     {name: 'Nota final'}
                  ]
});

store_grid_metas.loadData(data_metas);
```

The "radiogrid" function:

```
function radiogrid (value) {
return "<input type='radio' name = 'primaryRadioMetaUno' " + (value ? "checked='checked'" : "") + ">";
}
```

And this is the grid:

```
var grid_metas = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

            store       : store_grid_metas,
            id          : 'grid_metas',
            stripeRows  : true,
            height      :  500,
            width       : '100%',
            autoScroll  : true,
            frame       : true,
            border      : true,
            columnLines : true,
            stateful    : true,
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            items: [{

                                xtype: 'button',
                                itemId: 'btn_guardar_meta',
                                icon: '../../icons/add.png',
                                scale: 'small',
                                text: '<b>INGRESAR METAS</b>',
                                handler: function(){

                                      //modal_agregar_metas();

                                }
                  }],

            columns:[{ 
                      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                      dataIndex: 'Meta',name: '',
                      header: 'Meta',
                      sortable: true,
                      grupable:true,
                      width: 400,                    
                  },{ 
                      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                      dataIndex: '100%',name: '',
                      header: '100%',
                      sortable: true,
                      grupable:true,
                      align: 'center',
                      width: 50,
                      renderer : radiogrid               
                  },{ 
                      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                      dataIndex: '75%',name: '',
                      header: '75%',
                      sortable: true,
                      grupable:true,
                      align: 'center',
                      width: 50,
                      renderer : radiogrid
                  },{ 
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                      dataIndex: '50%',name: '',
                      header: '50%',
                      sortable: true,
                      grupable:true,
                      align: 'center',
                      width: 50,
                      renderer : radiogrid
                  },{ 
                      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                      dataIndex: '25%',name: '',
                      header: '25%',
                      sortable: true,
                      grupable:true,
                      align: 'center',
                      width: 50,
                      renderer : radiogrid
                  },{ 
                      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                      dataIndex: '0%',name: '',
                      header: '0%',
                      sortable: true,
                      grupable:true,
                      align: 'center',
                      width: 50,
                      renderer : radiogrid
                  },{ 
                      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                      dataIndex: 'Ponderación',name: '',
                      header: 'Ponderación',
                      sortable: true,
                      grupable:true,
                      width: 150
                  },{ 
                      xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                      dataIndex: 'Nota final',name: '',
                      header: 'Nota final',
                      sortable: true,
                      grupable:true,
                      width: 150
                  }],


})
```

The code display this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try a listener on the grid that handles the [cellclick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-event-cellclick) event. Using the parameters that Ext passes to this handler, you can access the store record to set or get values as needed:

```
function(grid, rowIndex, columnIndex, e) {
    var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);  // Get the Record
    var fieldName = grid.getColumnModel().getDataIndex(columnIndex); // Get field name
    var data = record.get(fieldName);
}
```